# Problems with UIView clearColor

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uikit

I am working on building a framework for iOS. The way that works is that say an app uses my framework and calls it to work. The framework presents a view controller on top of the calling app.

Now where I'm stuck is that I have set the view's background color to be `clearColor`. But whenever the view controller of the framework loads up, the background is set to Black. If i try setting the color to something like Red, Blue, etc. it works perfectly fine. But when I set it to `clearColor` it shows a Black screen!

I have seen some questions regarding the same matter but all of them suggest setting transparency of the view to NO. I have done that already and it isn't working. So please suggest a solution other than the one that requires you to set the opaque property.

Thanks.

Comment: Plese show some code. There could be a view "behind" the one who's background you try to set. And the view in the background could be black.

Comment: You can try adding an `IBOutlet` and setting the background to `nil`. Like this: `tableViewBackground.backgroundView = nil;` This will be put in the `-(void)viewDidLoad`

Comment: Is that viewController presented modally?

Comment: its called using [[self delegate] presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:^{}];

Comment: Right, that is modally which will prevent any kind of transparency. Follow the hint given by @ChrisWagner, that is the way to accomplish the effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to present the view controller, rather you want to add your view controller's view as a subview to the currently presented view controller.

That is if I am understanding you correctly, it sounds like you want to create an overlay.

Comment: Yeah it's more of an overlay that I need to add. Your point sounds good. Shall work and check. I'll tick your answer correct when it's working. Thanks @Chris Wagner

Comment: Another approach is creating a new UIWindow, which depending on what you are trying to do make work better for you.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that if the view with a background of `clearColor` is the only view, the screen will be black because the view can't be clear if there is nothing under it. To use a view with a clear color, there would have to be a view under it.

Comment: Yes. The view under it had some background color.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem while setting `clearColor` from within `initWithFrame:` for a custom UIView. Letting the superview set the background color to `clearColor` worked.

```
CustomView *uv = [[CustiomView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
uv.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[self.view addSubview:cv];
```